# box-shadow on <button> is cut off on Safari ONLY

Tags: css, safari

I'm trying to achieve a 'press' button effect with a `<button>` and a `<span>` but for some reason the shadow is getting cut off on Safari ONLY.

I'm using two tags here because that's a limitation of the website i'm editing, I can't change the markup.

It's simple as this, HTML:

```
<button><span>A simple fucking button</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;  
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

button span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  border-radius: 2em;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px -2px #bfbfbf,
            0px 5px 0px 0px black;
}

button:active,
button:hover {
  color: inherit;
}

button:hover {
  span {
    transform: translate(0px, 5px);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
}
```

codepen.io example:
https://codepen.io/marlonmarcello/pen/dVBKpd

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to dropping the span, then the button and styles can be adjusted to achieve the desired effect:

https://codepen.io/enquiren/pen/qMzLrd

```css
button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;  
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  &.pushable {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    border-radius: 2em;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px -2px #bfbfbf,
                0px 5px 0px 0px black;
    
    &:hover {
      transform: translate(0px, 5px);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="pushable">A simple button</button>
```